# NHibernate ClassMapping creates automatic a unique key

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I use NHibernate with ClassMapping. I created an index on one of the properties, like this:

```
public class ShopMapping : ClassMapping<Shop>
    {
        public ShopMapping()
        {
            Table("Shops");
            Id(p => p.Id, m => m.Generator(NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Generators.GuidComb));

            Property(p => p.CountryCode, m =>
            {
                m.Length(10);
                m.NotNullable(true);
                m.Index("ShopCountryCodeIdx");
                m.Unique(false);
            });

        }
    }
```

This generates the index called ShopCountryCodeIdx, but I got also a unique index, called 'CountryCode' on the same column. I tried it with an without m.Unique(false), but no effects.
I just moved to a new pc. Old pc: VS2012 on 32bitand new pc: VS2015 on 64bit. NHiberate version is on both the same (3.4.1.4). Database is MySQL 5.7 (on old machine I used MySQL 5.5).
How is this possible?

Comment: I just re-run the code (with drop database object etc) and recreate the tables with m.Unique(false). That results still in an extra index 'CountryCode' (not unique). I forgot to tell that the property CountryCode does exists in a couple more objects. All these object-related tables got an extra index 'CountryCode'.

Comment: Edit: run into some caching problems I guess. CountryCode index is still 'unique'... :(

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem found. I had in one of my other ClassMapping classes an unique index across three columns. One of the was also a CountryCode column. That results in this strange behavior.

```
Property(p => p.CountryCode, m =>
        {
            m.Length(10);
            m.NotNullable(true);
            m.Index("PanelShopCountryCodeIdx");
            //m.UniqueKey("UK_psPanelShopnrIdx");
        });
        Property(p => p.ShopNr, m =>
        {
            m.Length(25);
            m.NotNullable(true);
            //m.UniqueKey("UK_psPanelShopnrIdx");
        });
        Property(p => p.PanelCode, m =>
        {
            m.Length(25);
            m.NotNullable(true);
           // m.UniqueKey("UK_psPanelShopnrIdx");
        });
```

Getting rid of those m.UniqueKey statements, solved the problem (which let me with another challenge, how to create in this scenario a unique index across three columns from which one column has also an own (non unique) index...